# iterate through mongoose.models

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to get all mongoose model names and iterate through them at view (`test.jade`)

**route**

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
     var models = mongoose.models;
     console.log(models); 
     res.render('test',{data:models});
})
```

i got this log at node console:

```
{ User: 
   { [Function: model]
     base: 
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Circular],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'User',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Circular],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: '',
        pass: '',
        name: 'simpleblog',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema: 
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: [],
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     options: undefined,
     collection: 
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'users',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } },
  Comment: 
   { [Function: model]
     base: 
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Circular],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Comment',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Circular],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: '',
        pass: '',
        name: 'simpleblog',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema: 
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     options: undefined,
     collection: 
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'comments',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } },
  Article: 
   { [Function: model]
     base: 
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Circular],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Article',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Circular],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: '',
        pass: '',
        name: 'simpleblog',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema: 
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     options: undefined,
     collection: 
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'articles',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } } }
```

**view**

```
for(var prop in data)
   p #{prop}: #{data[prop]}
```

the problem is that I couldn't get any result after iteration operation at view

Comment: Does the rest of the view from `test.jade` get rendered correctly? If you add `console.log(models)` right after `router.get(...){`, do you see anything get printed in the node console?

Comment: @pbkhrv  `test.jade`  is getting rendered correctly i have tested it. and i also loged the models inside router.get i got result which i will share it at my next edit.

Comment: I am expecting to see something like the node.js log ... currently i don't see any output at my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route, try this:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
     var models = Object.keys(mongoose.models);
     var schemas = mongoose.modelSchemas;
     res.render('test',{models: models, schemas: schemas});
})
```

Then in your layout file, try this (assuming you're using jade)

```
each model in models
    p #{model} : 
        each path in schemas[model].paths
            div #{JSON.stringify(path)}
```

Comment: The main problem was the way you were handling the loop in your Jade file. You were using `for(var prop in data)`, which is not valid for Jade, so it was ignoring that line. Since it was ignoring that line when it got to the next line `prop` was undefined, so you didn't get any output.

Comment: yes i get exactly what i want with your edits.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but it looks like you are possibly logging the function that builds the models, and not an instance of the models data.